# CMD batch file - xcopy won't copy directory with accented character in its name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am writing a batch file, that would copy all files from my folder "Ostatní" (a Czech name for Other). However, when I try to copy from there in the batch file, it gives me an error :

```
File not found - OstatnÝ
```

As you can see, it is different from what I wrote into the script - I think there is some error with encoding, since when I open cmd manually and enter the xcopy command, it works flawlessly - I have even tried some desperate things like using Ostatn* - but that also works only in cmd but not in the batch file.

How can I make this work ?

Thank you very much

EDIT : the line of code

```
xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /y "C:\Users\boris\Desktop\Ostatní" "D:\backup"
```

Comment: Show the (relevant portion of the) code of your batch file!

Comment: @aschipfl - added to the main post

Comment: What is output when you type `DIR/B/AD "C:\Users\boris\Desktop\Ostatn*"`?

Comment: @RaymondChen thank you, I will try to find another one. Compo : "Ostatní" (without quotes)